# I'm writing a code to take a user input and provide its documentation in python. But the string in the user input is used with quotes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
user_input = input("\nWhat can I help you with? ")
user_input = user_input.strip('"')
print("\n>>"+user_input.__doc__)
```

In the above code the user_input.**doc** is causing the following problem:

> str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
> Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
> errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
> that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
> Otherwise, returns the result of object.**str**() (if defined)
> or repr(object).
> encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
> errors defaults to 'strict'.

Can anyone help me on removing quotes from user_input when I use it with `__doc__`?

Comment: `user_input` is a string, not the object named by the string.

Comment: You could try `globals()[user_input].__doc__`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
user_input = input("\nWhat can I help you with? ")
user_input = user_input.strip('"')
print("\n>>"+eval(user_input).__doc__)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your code isn't looking up any function. A string will never translate to a function even if it shares the name. The function will return a string of your input, and you are then accessing that strings documentations.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?